# Global symbol requires explicit package

Tags: perl, file

What I am doing wrong? Opened file is not empty. But I'm still getting

> Global symbol "$tabbb" requires explicit package name at mix.pl line 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "<", "seeds.data" or die $!;
my @tab = <FILE>;
print @$tab;
```

Comment: Is that really the error message? There's no variable named `$tabbb`.

Comment: Don't use bare word file handles.  Use `my $fh` instead.

Comment: Sorry, error was copied from older "version"

Comment: Unfortunately file was emtpy, and that was a problem...

Answer (score 2):

you want `print @tab;` instead of `print @$tab;`.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly used `use strict` and `use warnings`, and one of the benefits is that Perl will warn you if you use a variable you haven't declared. The error message

> Global symbol "$tabbb" requires explicit package name at mix.pl line 8.

is saying that, because you are using `strict`, you cannot refer to a variable called `$tabbb` that hasn't been declared. Your line

```
print @$tab;
```

is dereferencing the scalar variable `$tab` as an array, and since you haven't declared a `$tab` I imagine that is what the error message means. However you *do* have an array variable `@tab` that contains the contents of the file you opened, so write

```
print @tab;
```

instead.

Best of all, read the file line-by-line and write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'seeds.data' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  print;
}
```